# Alerting a remote computer if any app other than a specific one is opened

Tags: windows, security

I'm taking an exam in packet tracer.

For security purposes, I need a solution that will alert me if my students open any apps other than the packet tracer.

Comment: Make the application a shell. Or run it in Kiosk Mode.

Comment: This is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/267029). [Just use kiosk mode](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/setup-kiosk-digital-signage).

Comment: Is there any easy solution to use non Windows apps (.exe) in kiosk mode???

Comment: So what kind of app exactly?